# C# Parse string into arrays for HighCharts

Tags: c#, highcharts, format

I get some dynamic data from a webserver in this format:

```
Series1
7   2       
8   11      
9   5       
10  4

¤Series2
6   0,1     
7   2,2     
8   10,4    
9   6,9     
10  5,1     
11  2,7     
12  3,9     
13  3,6     
14  4       
15  2,3     
16  0,3     
17  0       
18  0       
21  0       
22  0

¤Series3
6   0,2     
7   2,1     
8   9,4     
9   6,4     
10  4,6     
11  2,2     
12  3       
13  3,2     
14  4,3     
15  2,2     
16  0,6     
17  0,1     
18  0       
21  0       
22  0,1
```

So series names, x-axis and y-axis data are separated by '¤'.

I need to put this data in a HighChart chart with the following required format:

```
chart.SetXAxis(new XAxis
{
     Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
});

 chart.SetSeries(new[]
 {
       new Series {
                        Name = "Series1",
                        Type = DotNet.Highcharts.Enums.ChartTypes.Column,
                        Data = new Data
                    (new object[] { 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 }) },
                    new Series {
                        Name = "Series2",
                        Data = new Data
                    (new object[]{ 129.9, 171.5, 10.4, 29.2, 44.0, 76.0, 35.6, 48.5, 21.4, 19.1, 9.56, 94.4 }) }
                }
                );
```

I have tried a lot to format this data with a lot of array-splitting and creating dictionaries... but i keep failing. One of the hard parts, is that the series1 in this example only has data for 7,8,9,10 (XAxis) while the other series has data for 6 to 22 (example) So i can not expect all the series to have data for the same x-values.

Do anyone have the knowledge/skills for an algorithm to format this data?
:)

Answer (score 0):

The First thing you need to do is decide on a common format

looking at what you have i would says your stuck with

string series,
int ID,
int[] cord,

Sudo Code

```
seriesString = OriginalString.SplitBySeries
seriesRow = seriesString.SplitByNewLine

series = seriesRow.First
for each row that isn't first
    col = row.SplitByWhitespace
    id = col.first
    cord = col.Last.SplitbyComma
```

in C# that would look like

```
struct DataItem
{
    string Series{get;set;}
    int ID{get;set;}
    int[] Cord{get;set;}
}

string seriesSeperator = <Seperator string>
string colSeperator = <Seperator string>
List<DataItem> items

foreach(string series in OriginalString.Split(seriesSeperator)
{
    var rows = serive.Split(Environment.Newline);
    var name = series[0];
    for(int i = 1;i<series.Lenth;i++)
    {
        var col = row.Split(colSeperator );
        items.Add( new DataIten
        {
            Series = name,
            ID = int.Parse(col[0]),
            cord = col[1].Split(",").Select(c=>int.Parse(c)).ToArray()
        });
    }
}
```

Note code is for Guidance only and has not been tested

then once you have the list of items you can build your graph

Answer (score 0):

Try code below. I used StreamReader to read from file but you can use StringReader to read from a string instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        public enum State
        {
            FIND_GROUP,
            GET_GROUP
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            Series series = null;
            State state = State.FIND_GROUP;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_GROUP:
                            series = new Series();
                            series.name = inputLine.Replace("�", "");
                            Series.series.Add(series);
                            state = State.GET_GROUP;
                            break;
                        case State.GET_GROUP:
                            string[] numbers = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            series.values.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>(
                                int.Parse(numbers[0]),
                                numbers[1].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList()
                            ));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    state = State.FIND_GROUP;
                }
            }

        }
     }
    public class Series
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public static List<Series> series = new List<Series>();
        public List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>> values { get; set; }
        public Series()
        {
            values = new List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>();
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggesion. It looks promising. There is a misunderstanding though. You can't rely on the `StartsWith("Series")`, because _Series1_, _Series2_ and _Series3_ were just examples. In the actual data, these are replaced with names for the charts. Like "Banana", "Apple", "Orange" or something else (unknown)

Comment: I there always a blank row between groups?  I need a specific method for determining when a group ends.